# Async Each is not updating if passed an array parameter that has more than 100 values

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am currently trying to update an array with order numbers using async.each in order for it to run in parallel. However, it seems that the larger the array length the more it misses to update. How can I update every order numbers in the array regardless of the array length in 
parallel?

Below I have my javascript code attached:

```
axios.post(`/api/admin/add-into-batch`, {orders})
.then(function(data){
    location.reload();
})


router.post('/admin/add-into-batch', function (req, res, next) {
    // req.body.orders = [1,2,3,4,..,120]
    async.each(req.body.orders, function(order, cb){
        CurrentOrder.findByIdAndUpdate(order._id, order, function(err, data){
            if (err) return next(err)
            cb()
        })
    }, function(err) {
    // if any of the update produced an error, err would equal that error
    if( err ) {
      // One of the iterations produced an error.
            // All processing will now stop.
            next(err)
    } else {
            return res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    })
})
```

Comment: If `findByIdAndUpdate()` is a database query, you might want to batch your concurrency to limit the amount of pending requests at any given time by using [`eachLimit()`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems to be working well. @PatrickRoberts

Comment: Just an FYI, if you have 100s of orders in one request, you should look into aggregating those transactions into a fewer database queries, that would save a lot of bandwidth and make your server less susceptible to DDoS.